# Why is my implode function empty

Tags: php

I have created a session and after doing `print_r($_SESSION['boxdest2']);` shows these values: 'DEMO9992,DEMO9963'.

The problem is that in the code I am using, it is empty. Obviously my code is wrong and would be grateful if someone could point out my error. thanks

```
$boxes = implode(',', $_SESSION['boxdest2']);
```

Comment: Pretty sure `explode` will get the result you want.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove comma and display records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40866465/how-to-remove-comma-and-display-records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem is here:**

> $boxes = implode(',', $_SESSION['boxdest2']);

This is the problem of your code `implode` expects 2 parameter to be array but you gave a string.
If you want to split string with `,` then you can use `explode` instead of `implode`

This would have worked fine if you had an array like this

```
Array(
  'DEMO9992',
  'DEMO9963'
)
```

Comment: Sahil if I echo $boxes it just prints Array

Comment: @user1532468 Can you share that array in your post?

Comment: @user1532468 you'll have to var_dump() an array in order to see its content.

Comment: @user1532468 Dont echo just use `print_r($boxes)`, `echo` is for string only and `print_r` is for expression

Comment: This is the result of print_r($boxes): Array ( [0] => DEMO9992 [1] => DEMO9963 )

Comment: Is this not your expected output? I think you are using `explode` which is giving an array and thats fine

Comment: @user1532468 can you share your expected output in your post, so that we can help you out?

Comment: @Sahil yes but I need to assign values to variable to use in report. For example, $box = values of array. At the moment I can do nothing with them. Thanks

Comment: @Sahil What if I want to do more than 2 items? These are created dynamically and could be as many as 100. thanks

Comment: This works well but need to create var to use elsewhere on page or report. Thanks $x = explode(',', $_SESSION['boxdest2']);
    foreach ($x as $value)
     {
        echo "( " . $value . " )" . ' ';
     }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142523/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-user1532468).

Answer (score 3):

`implode()` joins an array into a string. You want `explode()`, which splits a string into an array.